# error to change dynamically background url / image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am changing `background:url('image-file') or img's src` dynamically and it's doing as i expected but one problem i am getting when the file has space between the name e.g. `file name.gif (Not loading) or file-name.gif (load successfully)`

```
  var file-src = ../context/image file.jpg  /*not changing */
              /* ../context/image-file.jpg : changes   */

 if(this.is('img')){   /* 'this' is selecter */
    this.attr('src', file_src);
    }else{
    this.css('background','url('+ file_src +')');
    }
```

as far as i am not very sure why such files are not loading, i just try my best to find out the reason but i want to know if there could be any other reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cover filename by quote. Your code should be change to:

```
var file-src = '../context/image file.jpg';

this.css('background',"url('"+ file_src + "')");
```

Comment: great, it's working now but i am wondering why other files were loading successfully without any error. anyway thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

URLs cannot have spaces in them.  A space should be represented by a %20.  You can use the [encodeURI function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to properly encode special characters.

Your javascript also doesn't look correct as strings must be quoted, but I'm assuming that's just a shortcut you took when posting.

Comment: thanks jfriend00, i just quoted the string and it's working now for all types but you gave me another idea to avoid such issue. thanks.